# Actionsheet popover background truns to black before popover gets dismissed in ios 9

Tags: objective-c, ios9

Using following:

```
  [self.actionSheetPostOptions showFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES];
```

also tried

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                       message:nil
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *actnCamera = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                 }];

UIAlertAction *actnLibrary = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Library" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                 }];

[alertController addAction:actnLibrary];
[alertController addAction:actnCamera];
[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController
                                                             popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but still getting same issue while dismissing.

Update **iOS 11**: This issue no longer exists in iOS 11.

Comment: Having same issue. For me, it works fine when I change position from right side of the screen to the left. Any updates?

Comment: In my case, Popover should be from right button only. So added a workaround, disabling view animations on presentations. enabling back after dismiss. it solved my issue.

Comment: same issue here. how did you disable view animations?

Comment: use [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; to disable animation on presentation of UIAlertController and enable ([UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];) back on dismiss.

Comment: try to  present in main queue

Comment: Update in iOS 11: this issue no longer exists in iOS 11.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this on real Device, too? I saw the same behavior when running in iOS Simulator but on the Device it works fine.

Comment: For me issue on Device only. In simulator working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have added workaround for this by disabling view animations on actionsheet presentation and enabling back after dismissal of sheet.

Use below to disable view animations before presentation of UIAlertController.

```
 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```

and enable view animations after dismissal of UIAlertController.

```
 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Sure, its not a solution but it may help.

Comment: Update in iOS 11: this issue no longer exists in iOS 11.